# How to find the total after using count and group_contat

Tags: mysql, join, count, sum, group-concat

So I was making a table that shows the total, but the total amount is not correct.

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/de76b6e/12

Expected output:

| ClientName | ClientPhone | Address | Services | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Chan Tai Man | 12345678 | 82 Kennedy Street, Wan Chai | Carpets(2),Sofas(1) | 1120 |
| Wong Kai tung | 28473465 | 24 Kennedy Road, Wan Chai | Mattresses(1) | 100 |
| Chan Tai Man | 63827482 | 26 Queen Road East, Wan Chai | Carpets(1) | 500 |

Actual output:

| ClientName | ClientPhone | Address | Services | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Chan Tai Man | 12345678 | 82 Kennedy Street, Wan Chai | Carpets(2),Sofas(1) | 620 |
| Wong Kai tung | 28473465 | 24 Kennedy Road, Wan Chai | Mattresses(1) | 100 |
| Chan Tai Man | 63827482 | 26 Queen Road East, Wan Chai | Carpets(1) | 500 |

My Data:

```
INSERT INTO MAIN VALUES( 
    null,'Carpets', '2021-03-09', '1');  
INSERT INTO MAIN VALUES( 
    null,'Sofas', '2021-03-09', '1');
INSERT INTO MAIN VALUES( 
    null,'Mattresses', '2021-03-10', '2');
INSERT INTO MAIN VALUES( 
    null,'Carpets', '2021-03-11', '3');
INSERT INTO MAIN VALUES( 
    null,'Carpets', '2021-03-11', '1');

  
 
/*****  CREATE SERVICE  **************************************************/
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS SERVICE;
CREATE TABLE SERVICE(
  ServiceName                       VarChar(20)   NOT NULL,
  CPS                               Numeric(20)   NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT          SERVICE_PK            PRIMARY KEY(ServiceName)
    );

/*****   SERVICE DATA   ***********************************************************/

INSERT INTO SERVICE VALUES('Carpets', 500);
INSERT INTO SERVICE VALUES('Sofas', 120);
INSERT INTO SERVICE VALUES('Mattresses', 100);
INSERT INTO SERVICE VALUES('Curtains', 80);



/*****   CREATE CLIENT   ***********************************************************/
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS CLIENT;
CREATE TABLE CLIENT (
    ClientID                            Int      auto_increment  NOT NULL,
    ClientName                      Char (50)           NOT NULL,
    ClientPhone                              Int (8)                    NOT NULL,
    Address                              VarChar(100)               NULL,
    CONSTRAINT        CLIENT_PK             PRIMARY KEY(ClientID)
    );

/*****   CLIENT DATA   *************************************************************/

INSERT INTO CLIENT VALUES(
    null,'Chan Tai Man', '12345678', '82 Kennedy Street, Wan Chai');
INSERT INTO CLIENT VALUES(
    null,'Wong Kai tung', '28473465', '24 Kennedy Road, Wan Chai');
INSERT INTO CLIENT VALUES(
    null,'Chan Tai Man', '63827482', '26 Queen Road East, Wan Chai');

/***********************************************************************************/
```

My code:

```
SELECT CLIENT.ClientName, CLIENT.ClientPhone, CLIENT.Address, 
GROUP_CONCAT(MAIN.Num) AS Services,
SUM(SERVICE.CPS) AS Total
FROM (
  SELECT DOS, InvoiceID, ClientID, ServiceName, 
  CONCAT(ServiceName, '(', count(ServiceName), ')') AS Num
  From MAIN
  GROUP BY ClientID, ServiceName
  ) MAIN
LEFT JOIN CLIENT ON MAIN.ClientID = CLIENT.ClientID 
LEFT JOIN SERVICE ON MAIN.ServiceName = SERVICE.ServiceName
GROUP BY CLIENT.ClientID
ORDER BY MAIN.DOS;
```

Comment: Typically, you'd GROUP BY all non-aggregated columns in the SELECT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are making the SUM after you have already agregated the values. You should make the sum and the JOIN to the service table inside your subquery like:

```
SELECT CLIENT.ClientName, CLIENT.ClientPhone, CLIENT.Address, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(MAIN.Num) AS Services,
       sum(main.Total) as total
FROM (
  SELECT DOS, InvoiceID, ClientID, main.ServiceName, 
         CONCAT(main.ServiceName, '(', count(main.ServiceName), ')') AS Num,
         SUM(SERVICE.CPS) AS Total
  From MAIN
  LEFT JOIN SERVICE ON MAIN.ServiceName = SERVICE.ServiceName
  GROUP BY ClientID, ServiceName
  ) MAIN
LEFT JOIN CLIENT ON MAIN.ClientID = CLIENT.ClientID 
GROUP BY CLIENT.ClientID
ORDER BY MAIN.DOS;
```

Besides that, I wouldn ´t use as alias the same name as the table name

Comment: I see, thank you for your reminder, I will change the name later. Thanks a lot.